# Can't run the gtk-hello app from the elementary OS developer tutorial

Tags: vala

After successfully compiling the `gtk-hello.vala` file from the official elementary OS tutorial, I tried to run the gtk-hello file from terminal with the command `./gtk-hello`
However it never runs because I always get the same error/warning:

```
** (gtk-hello:25080): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-AIV4rkwx0f: Connection refused
```

After some quick searching online, I read that some people had this issue with GTK 2.0 but that doesn't seem right to me, since I compiled it with the command `valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 gtk-hello.vala`.

Comment: Which version of elementary OS are you using?